# make a program in c that reads string of characters with getchar and print it with putchar

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c, len = 0;

    // Read characters from the standard input stream until the end of the
    // input stream is reached
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        len++;
    }

    // Set the value of MAX_LEN to the length of the string
    #define MAX_LEN len

    char str[MAX_LEN];
    int i = 0;

    // Read characters from the standard input stream again
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && i < MAX_LEN - 1) {
        // Store the character in the str array
        str[i++] = c;
    }

    // Add a null character to the end of the string
    str[i] = '\0';

    // Print the string to the standard output stream
    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        putchar(str[i++]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I keep writing the string in the cotrol pannel  but i couldnt finde how the code can find the end of the input stream is reached help THE CODE WORKS without bugs[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge63J.png)
am using vs code and also used codeblocks same problem

plz help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw4of.png)TRIED CTRL Z BUT in the second time the process is finished

Comment: I believe you have to press ```Ctrl + D``` to signal ```EOF```.

Comment: Or, if you are using Microsoft Windows, you must press `CTRL-Z`.

Comment: I TRIED CTRL-Z but nothing am using windows

Comment: @AzizMessaoud: Try pressing the `ENTER` key, then `CTRL-Z`, and then `ENTER` again.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel here you go bro tried everything but nothing to my problem

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to retract my close vote after you posted your complete code. I am now voting to reopen the question.

Comment: Please post the output as text into the question, instead of an image. You may want to read this: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `getchar` returns `EOF`, you are calling `getchar` again, until it returns `EOF` again or until `i` reaches `MAX_LEN - 1`. That is why you must press <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> twice. If you want to only have to press <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> once, then you should only have one loop in which you call `getchar`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 200

int main( void )
{
    char str[MAX_LEN];
    int c, len = 0;

    //read input into memory buffer until EOF
    while ( (c=getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        str[len++] = c;
    }

    //add a null character to the end of the string
    str[len] = '\0';

    //print the string using putchar in a loop
    for ( int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        putchar( str[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```